# How can I merge segments to one segment in QGIS (picture inside) and than get the center of each road?

Tags: qgis

I want to run a process that will make a table with lots of roads into distinct table of roads and than calculate the center of each road.

How can I auto merge segments with same name to one long segment ?

Attached example of 1 road built from 3 different segments , I want to make it one road and have it center point. (so I can zoom on it from OpenLayers)

[image]

Comment: Do you need the values of the center point or do you need it for styling purposes? A marker line style has the option to put a marker on the line center.

Comment: I need it so I can setCenter on street using OpenLayers from a dropdownlist that will read the data after I export it to db.

Answer (score 3):

To auto-merge features based on attributes I recommend the Dissolve-tool (Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools).

**Edit:**

Appearently dissolve does not work on lines... You will have to use the Vector-> Geometry Tools-> Singleparts to Multipart tool.

Comment: I'm trying to use the tool but the Combo box of Input vector layer won't open (like its empty) while I have only 1 vector layer (Layer -> Add Vector Layer) in the project.

Any idea why ?

Comment: What version of ftools/GDAL tolls do you have? (Check the plugin-installer)

Comment: GDalTool ver 1.2.29 
QGIS 1.8.0

Comment: Ftools 0.6.2 .
Any idea ?!

Comment: I'm kinda running out of ideas...  you could save the shape as a new file and try again, maybe that does the trick. Reinstalling ftools/GDAL tools is also an option.

Comment: Still no go , the weird thing is that I CAN do Difference , Union and other commands , only the dissolve don't allow me to choose the vector layer.

Comment: Is there a way for you to share the file?

Comment: Yes : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1hy6uzccyfo6dy/GIS.rar

Comment: Gandalf , Were you able to do it with the file I shared?
When I browse table , I don't see the number of objects where changed...

Comment: The dropbox-file seems to be empty, so I could not use it. But using the singlepart to multipart tool I was able to merge some lines of my own.

Comment: Oh , no idea why it happened.
Ill check it again.

Comment: Updated link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1hy6uzccyfo6dy/GIS.rar